# FileChooserDialog not closing until function has exited. - Python GTK

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I have a FileChooserDialog, and when I call file_picker.destroy it won't exit until the entire function has exited. How can I make it destroy instantly and still execute the rest of the code in the function? It just hangs until the youtube-dl has finished. My code:

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("youtube-dl-gtk.glade")

window = builder.get_object("window")
window.show_all()

file_picker = builder.get_object("file_picker")

builder.get_objects()

folder = None

def youtube_dl_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print(d['filename'])

class youtube_dl_logger(object):
    def debug(self, msg):
        pass

    def warning(self, msg):
        pass

    def error(self, msg):
        print(msg)

def close_folder(button):
  file_picker.hide()

def download_video():
  url = builder.get_object("url")
  url = url.get_text()
  os.chdir(folder)
  ydl_opts = {
    'logger': youtube_dl_logger(),
    'progress_hooks': [youtube_dl_hook],
  }

  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])


def choose_folder(button):
  file_picker.show_all()

def open_folder(button):
  global folder
  folder = file_picker.get_current_folder()
  file_picker.destroy()
  download_video()

handlers = {
    "close_clicked_cb": Gtk.main_quit,
    "on_download_clicked": choose_folder,
    "on_open_folder_clicked": open_folder,
    "on_close_folder_clicked": close_folder
}

builder.connect_signals(handlers)

Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The display won't be updated until you return control to GTK's main loop. The best solution would be to do the download asynchronously so that it is not blocking the main loop.

Comment: How would I do that? @ptomato

Comment: I'm not familiar with youtube-dl's API. You would have to look at the API documentation to see if there is a method that would download asynchronously.